# WaitForSingleObject on a file handle?

Tags: windows, msvcrt

What happens when you call `WaitForSingleObject()` on a handle you've created with `CreateFile()` or `_get_osfhandle()`?

For reasons not worth explaining I would like to use `WaitForSingleObject()` to wait on a HANDLE that I've created with `_get_osfhandle(fd)`, where `fd` comes from a regular call to `_open()`. Is this possible?

I have tried it in practice, and on some machines it works as expected (the HANDLE is always in the signaled state because you can read more data from it), and on some machines `WaitForSingleObject()` will block indefinitely if you let it.

The MSDN page for `WaitForSingleObject()` says that the only supported things that it handles are "change notifications, console input, events, memory resource notifications, mutex, processes, semaphores, threads, and waitable timers."

Additionally, would it be different if I used `CreateFile()` instead of `_get_osfhandle()` on a CRT file descriptor?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't do it. As you can see, it has undefined behavior.

Even when the behavior is defined, it's defined in such a way as to be relatively not useful unless you don't like writing additional code. It is signaled when any asynchronous I/O operation on that handle completes, which does not generalize to tracking which I/O operation finished.

Why are you trying to wait on a file handle? Clearly the intent matters when you are doing something that isn't even supported well enough to not block indefinitely.

Comment: The operation is well defined. This is documented under [GetOverlappedResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683209.aspx). It may be discouraged, due to the way it's implemented, and may not be generally useful. There are better options. However, it is well defined.

Answer (score 7):

I found the following links. The concensus seems to me, don't do it.

- [Asynch IO explorer](http://www.flounder.com/asynchexplorer.htm#Waiting%20on%20a%20file%20handle)

> Waiting on a file handle
>
> When an I/O operation is started on an
>   asynchronous handle, the handle goes
>   into a non-signaled state.  Therefore,
>   when used in the context of a
>   WaitForSingleObject or
>   WaitForMultipleObjects operation, the
>   file handle will become signaled when
>   the I/O operation completes.  However,
>   Microsoft actively discourages this
>   technique; it does not generalize if
>   there exists more than one pending I/O
>   operation; the handle would become
>   signaled if any I/O operation
>   completed.  Therefore, although this
>   technique is feasible, it is not
>   considered best practice.

- [Egghead Cafe](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/forumarchives/win32programmerkernel/Dec2005/post25117352.asp):

> Use ReadDirectoryChangesW in
>   overlapped mode.  WaitForSingleObject
>   can     wait on the event in the
>   OVERLAPPED struct.
>
> You can also use the API
>   WaitForSingleObject() to wait on a
>   file   change if you use the following
>   change notification function:
>   FindFirstChangeNotification()
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/fileio/fs/findfirstchangenotification.asp
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/dllproc/base/waitforsingleobject.asp
>
> An interesting note on "evilness" of ReadDirectoryChangesW:
>   http://blogs.msdn.com/ericgu/archive/2005/10/07/478396.aspx