# Waitformultipleobjects returns invalid handle

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++

The code is below and it is part of a thread. pFileChange->m_hDirectory is of type HANDLE and pFileChange->m_eventFileChange if of type CEvent. CreateFile and ReadDirectoryChangesW return with a success. I am not able to figure out why i am getting an invalid handle status, please help!

```
UINT CFileChange::FileMontiorThread(LPVOID pArgs)
{
  CFileChange* pFileChange = NULL;

  pFileChange = (CFileChange*)pArgs;

  pFileChange = (CFileChange*)pArgs;

  CString str = pFileChange->m_strDirectory;

  LPSTR  strDirectory;
  strDirectory = str.GetBuffer(str.GetLength());
  PathRemoveFileSpec(strDirectory);

  DWORD dwBytes = 0;    
  vector<BYTE> m_Buffer;
  BOOL      m_bChildren;
  OVERLAPPED    m_Overlapped;
  HANDLE arrHandles[2] = { pFileChange->m_hDirectory,  pFileChange->m_eventFileChange };

  ::ZeroMemory(&m_Overlapped, sizeof(OVERLAPPED));
  DWORD dwBufferSize = 16384;
  m_Buffer.resize(dwBufferSize);
  m_bChildren = false;


  pFileChange->m_hDirectory = ::CreateFile(
     (LPCSTR)(LPCTSTR)strDirectory,
    FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,                
    FILE_SHARE_READ                     
    | FILE_SHARE_WRITE
    | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
    NULL,                               
    OPEN_EXISTING,                      
    FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS          
    | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
    NULL);                              

  if (pFileChange->m_hDirectory == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    return false;
  }

  BOOL success = ::ReadDirectoryChangesW(
    pFileChange->m_hDirectory,  // handle to directory
    &m_Buffer[0],                       // read results buffer
    m_Buffer.size(),                    // length of buffer
    m_bChildren,                        // monitoring option
    FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_CREATION |  FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME,        // filter conditions
    &dwBytes,                           // bytes returned
    &m_Overlapped,                      // overlapped buffer
    NULL);           // no completion routine

  DWORD dwWaitStatus;

  while (!pFileChange->m_bKillThread)
  {
    dwWaitStatus = WaitForMultipleObjects(2, arrHandles, FALSE, INFINITE);

   Switch(dwWaitStatus)
   {
     case WAIT_FAILED:
        {
            ULONG rc = 0;
            rc = ::GetLastError();
            LPVOID lpMsgBuf = NULL;
            ::FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                NULL,
                rc,
                MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), // Default  language
                (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
                0,
                NULL);
            CString strErrMsg;
            strErrMsg.Format(_T("%s, %s, Reason:%s"), "", "",         (LPTSTR)lpMsgBuf);
            break;
        }
    }
  }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You copy the handles into `arrHandles` too soon, *before* they are created.  That cannot work of course.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The answer was [provided by Hans Passant in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33273800/waitformultipleobjects-returns-invalid-handle/55501832#comment54355193_33273800):

> You copy the handles into `arrHandles` too soon, *before* they are created.  That cannot work of course.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, as it specifies [in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you can't wait on *any* type of handle.

[image: wait]

Waiting on a directory handle isn't going to do what you think it should. [Read this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/775014/2065121) and its answers for more information and background reading.

As it seems you're trying to create a folder monitor, perhaps [read this blog post](http://qualapps.blogspot.de/2010/05/understanding-readdirectorychangesw.html) for the correct way to use `ReadDirectoryChangesW`.